# converting json to object using gson throws object empty

Tags: java, json, gson

I try to convert a json to object but the object is always empty, I think that I have something wrong on the definition of the object but Im not very sure, the json Im trying to convert is:

```
{
    "cotizador": {
        "pagos": [{
            "monto": 163.83,
            "montoTotal": 678.52,
            "primerMonto": 187.03,
            "plazo": 4
        }, {
            "monto": 122.17,
            "montoTotal": 756.22,
            "primerMonto": 145.37,
            "plazo": 6
        }],
        "mensaje": {
            "codigo": 0,
            "descripcion": "Consulta Exitosa."
        }
    }
}
```

My main method is

```
String urlWS = "The url that return the json above";
URL url= new URL(urlWS);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent()));

Gson gsonOut = new Gson();
Cotizador cotizador=gsonOut.fromJson(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("cotizador"), Cotizador.class);
```

the **cotizador** object is always empty

this are my Objects:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="cotizador")
public class Cotizador {

    private Mensaje objMensaje;
    private List<Pago> lstPagos;

    public Cotizador() {
        this.objMensaje = new Mensaje();
        this.lstPagos = new ArrayList<Pago>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name="mensaje")
    public Mensaje getObjMensaje() {
        return objMensaje;
    }

    public void setObjMensaje(Mensaje objMensaje) {
        this.objMensaje = objMensaje;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="pagos")
    public List<Pago> getLstPagos() {
        return lstPagos;
    }

    public void setLstPagos(List<Pago> lstPagos) {
        this.lstPagos = lstPagos;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="mensaje")
public class Mensaje {

    private String strDescripcion;
    private int intCodigo;

    public Mensaje() {
        this.strDescripcion="";
        this.intCodigo=0;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="descripcion")
    public String getStrDescripcion() {
        return strDescripcion;
    }

    public void setStrDescripcion(String strDescripcion) {
        this.strDescripcion = strDescripcion;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="codigo")
    public int getIntCodigo() {
        return intCodigo;
    }

    public void setIntCodigo(int intCodigo) {
        this.intCodigo = intCodigo;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name="pago")
public class Pago {

    private int intPlazo;
    private double dblMonto;
    private double dblPrimerMonto;
    private double dblMontoTotal;

    public Pago() {
        this.intPlazo = 0;
        this.dblMonto = 0;
        this.dblPrimerMonto = 0;
        this.dblMontoTotal = 0;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="plazo")
    public int getIntPlazo() {
        return intPlazo;
    }

    public void setIntPlazo(int intPlazo) {
        this.intPlazo = intPlazo;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="monto")
    public double getDblMonto() {
        return dblMonto;
    }

    public void setDblMonto(double dblMonto) {
        this.dblMonto = dblMonto;
    }

    public double getDblPrimerMonto() {
        return dblPrimerMonto;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="primerMonto")
    public void setDblPrimerMonto(double dblPrimerMonto) {
        this.dblPrimerMonto = dblPrimerMonto;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="montoTotal")
    public double getDblMontoTotal() {
        return dblMontoTotal;
    }

    public void setDblMontoTotal(double dblMontoTotal) {
        this.dblMontoTotal = dblMontoTotal;
    }
}
```

Can someone know what I am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gson ignores XML annotations.

Comment: Indenting your code with filthy tabs is evil. Seriously though, your post could be improved with a little better formatting...

Comment: So if gson ignores the @xml anotations, instead of have the object like mensaje in the json, is better to change the name of that object to objMensaje?? so in that way the json will match with the object??

Comment: That or use Gson annotations, `@SerializedName`.